# Serialize/Deserialize a byte array in JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have a simple class with the following property:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Person
{
    ...
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Photograph"]
    public byte[] Photograph { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

but this doesn't work when I populate the Photograph property with an image and transfer over http.
This may sound like a simple question but I've yet to find a solution after looking online for hours, but, how do I serialise/deserialise a byte array in Json.NET? What attribute tags do I need, or, should I be doing this another way?
Many thanks!

Comment: Have you found a way to set the correct object's properties? The information is somewhat fragmented. I'm looking for a clean solution for the exact same problem. the `byte[]` should be converted to an array, not a string.

Comment: I think JSON.NET has issues with fixed-length arrays when you preserve references and type information.  When preserving type names in the "$type" member, it throws an error while trying to deserialize a fixed-length or read-only array.  You have to use `List<T>` instead, or use a JsonConverter to serialize the byte[] member.  It really needs to be fixed, because it should not have issues with such basic things.

Comment: Maybe you can use Base64 : `Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(downloadPth)`  and `Convert.FromBase64String(b64Str)`

Comment: Convert.ToBase64String worked for me! also ascii or utf8 are too small for store images data

Answer (score 40):

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(byte[] data) where T : class
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(data))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
        return JsonSerializer.Create().Deserialize(reader, typeof(T)) as T;
}
```

Comment: I like this answer, but you may want to throw an `Encoding.UTF8` argument into the second argument of the `StreamReader` constructor.  I am always a bit leery about using the default encoding.

Comment: Updated the snippet to have `Encoding.UTF8`

Comment: Notice this answer is *>2* years old. I'm not sure when the `System.Text.Json` namespace was added, but `JsonSerializer` doesn't have a `Create` method.

Comment: System.Text.Json is a part of .NET Core 3, which was made GA one month ago

Comment: Plus, the method mentioned is from Newtonsoft.Json

Answer (score 32):

You can convert the byte[] into a string then use the JsonConvert method to get the object:

```
var bytesAsString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
var person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(bytesAsString);
```

Comment: Be wary of using this method for large objects as you will get OutOfMemory Exceptions. Methods that use Stream(s) would be better equipped to handle OutOfMemory scenarios.

Comment: There are a few standards that use ASCII. JSON is not one of them. It uses UTF-8 (or, older standard, UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32—all easily distinguished, given that the data is JSON syntax).

Comment: @TomBlodget I have updated my answer to reflect your suggestions.

Comment: If you have "random" byte from photography, I think that you will get exceptions sometime:
T:System.ArgumentException: The byte array contains invalid Unicode code points.

In the [documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm) of Json.NET it is declared that a Byte[] will be serialized as a Base64 encoded string.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using [LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm), you can do this:

```
JObject.Parse(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));
```

The result will be a dynamic `JObject`.

While this might not be exactly what the OP was looking to do, it might come in handy for others looking to deserialize a `byte[]` that come across this question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29195482/7032856), you could use the one below in net core:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace <MyNameSpace>
{
    public static class ByteArrayExtensions
    {
        public static async Task<T> Deserialize<T>(this byte[] data) where T : class
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(data))
            {
                return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync(stream, typeof(T)) as T;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which may be considered to have the edge on readability:

```
var deserialized = await mySerializedByteArray.Deserialize<MyObjectClass>();
```

Comment: In STJ version 6, this can be collapsed to JsonSerializer.Deseralize<T> (I assume there is an Async variant too) - the `byte[]` gets `implict`ly converted to fit. `static TValue? Deserialize<TValue>(ReadOnlySpan<byte> utf8Json, JsonSerializerOptions? options = null)`